# Country selector in origin language

Tags: html, forms

I need to know if exist in the web some country selector in the origin language.
For example,

```
<select>
.
.
.
<option value="España"> España</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

Thx!!!!!

Comment: +1 not actually a bad question...

Answer (score 2):

There are many more options so I suggest you try the demonstration and view the documentation at [baymard.com/labs/country-selecto](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector)r. The open-source code is released under the MIT License and is available at GitHub.

**"Using principles of progressive enhancement we turn a standard drop-down into an advanced auto-complete field. This means the drop-down remains accessible, while providing a much better experience in modern browsers – handling typos, multiple spelling sequences, synonyms and prioritization."**